# Block diagram simplification find g(s)

Tags: block-diagram

I'm trying to simplify and find G(s) to solve this block diagram! But i don't know in the next part... can you help me?[![diagram
][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGwCP.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGwCP.jpg)

[image]

Comment: In the current revision of the question, there is no block diagram. Also please consider editing the question title to be less ambiguous.

Comment: Question rolled back after attempt to delete it despite an answer being given already.

Comment: @Transistor thanks for the roll back - the OP has even tried to delete the picture out of my answer too AND I've already amended it to protect his IP. Some folk are just never grateful.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is homework without effort.

Comment: @Andyaka The OP is probably trying to make it harder for their instructor to discover that they sought help on the internet.

Answer (score 2):

You need to take the original block diagram and start putting on it what you can see based on the various in/out relationships: -

[image]

So, just to give a little help, can you see that at the point with a blue circle that this is true: -

$$Y(s)\cdot s = K\cdot E(s) + \dfrac{K\cdot E(s)}{s+1}$$

This allows you to equate E(s) to Y(s). Can you take it from here?

Comment: No, I have left my answer.

Comment: You supplied the picture in your original question and I have made an answer using that picture. Without that picture my answer is voided. I'm not prepared to delete my answer. If you want an answer deleting you must take it up with moderators. Help has been provided to you (by me) and questions and answers on this site are for the pleasure of anyone seeking an answer. If you think that a modification to one of the control blocks might help may I suggest changing "4" to (say) "K" for example. I'm happy with that.

Comment: @sujan OK that's done now.

Comment: @sujan - what you tried to do was wrong - trying to remove the picture after we decided it could be amended is WRONG. If you want this question and answer to seen less then mark it as formally answered and then we can discuss making further amendments to it but DO NOT ATTEMPT TO DO THIS BEHIND MY BACK or you'll get no help and piss me off greatly.